# Don't refresh page when its mobile browser?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to make a page that when resize window less than 767, than refresh page one time.

So I searched lot of examples, and this is my code below

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(window).on('resize',function(){
    if ($(window).width() < 767) {   
      location.reload();  // refresh page 
    }
    else {  
      // width more than 768px for PC  
    }
}); 
});
```

The problem is that code works fine on PC browser. 
But, on the mobile browser, it keeps refreshing and refreshing infinitely...

What do I need to fix the code to not refresh page when its mobile ?
Only refresh  when window size less than 767px on PC ?

Comment: most likely the resize event is triggered on every load.

Comment: use this meta tag and it will most likely fix your problem => `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0" />`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make session cookie for that

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(window).on('resize',function(){
    if ($(window).width() < 767 && !document.cookie.match('refresh')) {   
    document.cookie = "refresh=1; expires=0; path=/"
      location.reload();  // refresh page 
    }
    else {  
      // width more than 768px for PC  
    }
}); 
});
```

check refresh cookie is not exists then refresh the page

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is set a session in php to remember if the user have done a resize

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $width = $('#content').width();
        $('#content img').css( 
        {
            'max-width': $width, 'height': 'auto'
        });

    });
</script>
```